# Extract data value out of div with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

If I have a div that looks like this:

```
<div class="random" data="20">Random</div>
```

Can I use jquery to output this data value out? I've searched but no luck...

Comment: [`$("div.random").attr("data")`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/attributes/) maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this.

```
<div class="random" data-value="20">Random</div>
```

```js
$('.random').data('value');
```

Comment: This way is more standards compliant due to using a `data-*` attribute, +1.

Comment: So I can store this into a variable and use it later on?

Comment: Yes on client side, not after postback , You will need to have global variable and store this value in that in document.ready function and use it in your script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery .attr to get the value of an attribute.

```
$('.random').attr('data');
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the data() function of jQuery, it reads those attributes that are prefixed with 'data-', so you need to qualify this with the key/name of your data, like 'data-myvalue'. Then you just pass the key to retrieve the value.

```
<div class="random" data-myvalue="20">Random</div>

$(".random").data("myvalue");
```

Or you can just use the attr() function and pass the entire attribute name. The advantage of the data() function is that it automatically parses the value to the appropriate type. So your example would return an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var getdiv= $('.random');
console.log(getdiv.attr('data'));
console.log(getdiv[0].innerText);
})
```

here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gjx0eepL/

Hope you want this only